# Hash Objects | Count Changes to a Parent ID over Time & LIst History of Related Child ID's

Tags: sas

I want to be able to input a table of parent ID's and count the number of times the ID has changed over time and also create a list of the parent ID and all the related children ID's, including the date the child ID's changed.  I experimented with the example data/ SAS hash objects code provided below, but it does not produce output for “want”.

I would like the output to show:
1). As of the current evaluation date (8/15/10), the # times the parent ID I specified (4) changed & the original ID:

| asof | origid | currid | changecount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08/15/2010 | 1 | 4 | 3 |

AND

2). The historical series of changes related to the current parent ID (4):

| changedate | oldid | newid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2010 | 1 | 2 |
| 07/01/2010 | 2 | 3 |
| 07/10/2010 | 3 | 4 |

```
data have;
    attrib oldid newid length=8 changedate informat=mmddyy10. format=mmddyy10.;
    input oldid newid changedate;
    datalines;
1 2 1/1/10
10 11 1/1/10
2 3 7/1/10
3 4 7/10/10
22 4 7/10/10
11 12 8/1/10
;
data want(keep=asof origid currid changecount);
    attrib asof format=mmddyy10. origid currid length=8;
     
    declare hash roots();
    roots.definekey('newid');
    roots.definedata('newid','changedate');
    roots.definedone();
     
    declare hash changes();
    changes.definekey('oldid');
    changes.definedata('newid','changedate');
    changes.definedone();
     
    do while (not done);
        set have end=done;
        if missing(oldid)
            then  roots.add();
            else changes.add();
    end;
     
    array  asofs (1) _temporary_('15-AUG-2010'd);
    declare  hiter  hi ('roots');
     
    do index = 1 to  dim(asofs);
        asof= asofs(index);
         
        do while (hi.next() eq 0);
            origid = newid;
            currid= .;
            do changecount = 0 by 1 while (changedate<= asof);
                currid = newid;
                if changes.find(key:newid) ne 0 then leave;
            end;
            output;
        end;
    end;
    stop;
run;
```

Comment: Is it true both 22 and 3 got changed to 4?  If so 4 has two paths to it. 1-2-3-4 and 22-4.  Do any of your data contain loops or cycles?  There have been several prior SAS questions about edge graphs and transaction paths that might be helpful to you

Comment: Hi Richard, That's correct- both 22 & 3 changed to 4. The table for item #1 should also have a record for 22 to 4. The ID's are unique and they cannot change back to a value they had in the past- is that what you mean by "loops". Thanks for the reference to edge graphs/ transaction paths. I'm not familiar with them but will check the literature.

Comment: In SAS it is bad practice to put your `set` statement in a `do ... end;` loop, because the data step itself is a loop. The `stop;` statement is also seldom useful for anything else but error handling.

Comment: Your example is VERY limited and does not show the complexity of your real problem. You risk to get irrelevant answars.

Comment: I think the dates in your example are wrong. Further, please give an example of an id that is never changed.

Answer (score 0):

In spite of the poor quality of your question, I wrote a program that might solve your problem. If you do the effort do improve your question, I might do the effort to debug it.

```
data have;
    attrib oldid newid length=8 changedate informat=mmddyy10. format=mmddyy10.;
    input oldid newid changedate;
    datalines;
1 2 1/1/10
10 11 1/1/10
2 3 7/1/10
3 4 7/10/10
22 4 7/10/10
11 12 8/1/10
;
data want(keep=asof origid currid changecount);
    attrib asof format=mmddyy10. origid currid length=8;
    
    * avoid re-declaring and loading the hash tables this way;
    if _N_ eq 1 then do;
        declare hash want();
        want.definekey('currid');
        want.definedata('asof', 'origid', 'changecount');
        want.definedone();
    end;
     
    set have end=done;
    if missng(oldid) then do;   
        origid = newid;
        currid = newid;
        asof = changedate;
        changecount = 0;
        if want.add();
            put 'ERROR: id new already exists: ' _N_= newid=;
    end;
    else if find_rc = want.find(key:oldid)then do;
        origid = oldid;
        currid = newid;
        asof = changedate;
        changecount = 1;
        want.add();
    end;
    else do;
        currid = newid;
        asof = changedate;
        changecount = changecount + 1;
        changes.replace();
    end;

    if done then do;
        declare  hiter  hi ('want');
        hi_rc = hi.first();      
        do while(not rc);
            output;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I get this error message when executing the code:  "DATA STEP Component Object Failure.  Aborted during COMPILATION phase. ERROR 557-185: Variable changes is not an object."

Comment: As explained, I am awaiting clarifications and corrections to you post